# Java application crashing and producing an error log file

Tags: java, jogl, worldwind, icepdf

I have a java application that uses ICEpdf to render pdf documents.  Recently, java has been crashing and producing this error log:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x76dca05b, pid=2224, tid=1072
#
# JRE version: 6.0_23-b05
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (19.0-b09 mixed mode windows-x86 )
# Problematic frame:
# C  [msvcrt.dll+0xa05b]
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x6148c000):  JavaThread "AWT-EventQueue-0" [_thread_in_native, id=1072, stack(0x61930000,0x61980000)]

siginfo: ExceptionCode=0xc0000005, writing address 0x00000000

Registers:
EAX=0x00000000, EBX=0x680b0020, ECX=0x0000333b, EDX=0x00000000
ESP=0x6197ef5c, EBP=0x6197ef64, ESI=0x680b0020, EDI=0x00000000
EIP=0x76dca05b, EFLAGS=0x00010212

Register to memory mapping:

EAX=0x00000000
0x00000000 is pointing to unknown location

EBX=0x680b0020
0x680b0020 is pointing to unknown location

ECX=0x0000333b
0x0000333b is pointing to unknown location

EDX=0x00000000
0x00000000 is pointing to unknown location

ESP=0x6197ef5c
0x6197ef5c is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x6148c000
"AWT-EventQueue-0" prio=6 tid=0x6148c000 nid=0x430 runnable [0x6197f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

EBP=0x6197ef64
0x6197ef64 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x6148c000
"AWT-EventQueue-0" prio=6 tid=0x6148c000 nid=0x430 runnable [0x6197f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

ESI=0x680b0020
0x680b0020 is pointing to unknown location

EDI=0x00000000
0x00000000 is pointing to unknown location


Top of Stack: (sp=0x6197ef5c)
0x6197ef5c:   00199d80 00000000 6197ef94 76dca00b
0x6197ef6c:   00000000 680b0020 00199d80 6197ef84
0x6197ef7c:   00000020 c4a8eee9 680b0020 00000000
0x6197ef8c:   61a76ae8 08000030 6197efb4 704f7a70
0x6197ef9c:   00000000 680b0020 00199da0 0a435d04
0x6197efac:   08000030 61a76ae8 6197efcc 704dc9ab
0x6197efbc:   08000030 61a76ae8 08000000 2c827bd4
0x6197efcc:   6197efe8 704e81b2 00000145 08000028 

Instructions: (pc=0x76dca05b)
0x76dca04b:   06 66 0f 6f 4e 10 66 0f 6f 56 20 66 0f 6f 5e 30
0x76dca05b:   66 0f 7f 07 66 0f 7f 4f 10 66 0f 7f 57 20 66 0f 


Stack: [0x61930000,0x61980000],  sp=0x6197ef5c,  free space=315k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
C  [msvcrt.dll+0xa05b]
C  [msvcrt.dll+0xa00b]
C  [prl_gldd.dll+0x27a70]
C  [prl_gldd.dll+0xc9ab]
C  [prl_gldd.dll+0x181b2]
C  [jogl.dll+0xf286]
j  com.sun.opengl.impl.GLImpl.glTexSubImage2D1(IIIIIIIILjava/lang/Object;I)V+0
j  com.sun.opengl.impl.GLImpl.glTexSubImage2D(IIIIIIIILjava/nio/Buffer;)V+85
j      com.sun.opengl.util.texture.Texture.updateSubImageImpl(Lcom/sun/opengl/util/texture/TextureData;IIIIIIII)V+658
j  com.sun.opengl.util.texture.Texture.updateImage(Lcom/sun/opengl/util/texture/TextureData;I)V+1001
j  com.sun.opengl.util.texture.Texture.updateImage(Lcom/sun/opengl/util/texture/TextureData;)V+3
j  com.sun.opengl.util.texture.Texture.<init>(Lcom/sun/opengl/util/texture/TextureData;)V+18
j  com.sun.opengl.util.texture.TextureIO.newTexture(Lcom/sun/opengl/util/texture/TextureData;)Lcom/sun/opengl/util/texture/Texture;+19
j  gov.nasa.worldwind.render.BasicWWTexture.initializeTexture(Lgov/nasa/worldwind/render/DrawContext;Ljava/lang/Object;)Lcom/sun/opengl/util/texture/Texture;+203
j  gov.nasa.worldwind.render.BasicWWTexture.bind(Lgov/nasa/worldwind/render/DrawContext;)Z+42
j  gov.nasa.worldwind.render.AbstractAnnotation.doDrawBackgroundTexture(Lgov/nasa/worldwind/render/DrawContext;IIDLgov/nasa/worldwind/geom/Position;Lgov/nasa/worldwind/render/WWTexture;)V+36
j  gov.nasa.worldwind.render.AbstractAnnotation.drawBackgroundImage(Lgov/nasa/worldwind/render/DrawContext;IIDLgov/nasa/worldwind/geom/Position;)V+35
j  gov.nasa.worldwind.render.AbstractAnnotation.drawContent(Lgov/nasa/worldwind/render/DrawContext;IIDLgov/nasa/worldwind/geom/Position;)V+19
j  gov.nasa.worldwind.render.AbstractAnnotation.doDraw(Lgov/nasa/worldwind/render/DrawContext;IIDLgov/nasa/worldwind/geom/Position;)V+35
j  gov.nasa.worldwind.render.AbstractAnnotation.draw(Lgov/nasa/worldwind/render/DrawContext;IIDLgov/nasa/worldwind/geom/Position;)V+47
j  gov.nasa.worldwind.render.AbstractAnnotation.drawTopLevelAnnotation(Lgov/nasa/worldwind/render/DrawContext;IIIIDDLgov/nasa/worldwind/geom/Position;)V+68
j  gov.nasa.worldwind.render.GlobeAnnotation.doRenderNow(Lgov/nasa/worldwind/render/DrawContext;)V+139
j  gov.nasa.worldwind.render.AbstractAnnotation.renderNow(Lgov/nasa/worldwind/render/DrawContext;)V+56
j  gov.nasa.worldwind.render.BasicAnnotationRenderer$OrderedAnnotation.doRender(Lgov/nasa/worldwind/render/DrawContext;Lgov/nasa/worldwind/render/BasicAnnotationRenderer$OrderedAnnotation;)V+22
j  gov.nasa.worldwind.render.BasicAnnotationRenderer$OrderedAnnotation.render(Lgov/nasa/worldwind/render/DrawContext;)V+20
J  gov.nasa.worldwind.AbstractSceneController.draw(Lgov/nasa/worldwind/render/DrawContext;)V
j  gov.nasa.worldwind.AbstractSceneController.repaint()I+49
j  gov.nasa.worldwind.WorldWindowGLAutoDrawable.doDisplay()I+4
j  gov.nasa.worldwind.WorldWindowGLAutoDrawable.display(Ljavax/media/opengl/GLAutoDrawable;)V+111
j  com.sun.opengl.impl.GLDrawableHelper.display(Ljavax/media/opengl/GLAutoDrawable;)V+29
j  javax.media.opengl.GLCanvas$DisplayAction.run()V+80
j  com.sun.opengl.impl.GLDrawableHelper.invokeGL(Ljavax/media/opengl/GLDrawable;Ljavax/media/opengl/GLContext;Ljava/lang/Runnable;Ljava/lang/Runnable;)V+418
j  javax.media.opengl.GLCanvas.maybeDoSingleThreadedWorkaround(Ljava/lang/Runnable;Ljava/lang/Runnable;)V+36
j  javax.media.opengl.GLCanvas.display()V+9
j  javax.media.opengl.GLCanvas.paint(Ljava/awt/Graphics;)V+125
j  javax.media.opengl.GLCanvas.update(Ljava/awt/Graphics;)V+2
j  sun.awt.RepaintArea.updateComponent(Ljava/awt/Component;Ljava/awt/Graphics;)V+6
j  sun.awt.RepaintArea.paint(Ljava/lang/Object;Z)V+263
j  sun.awt.windows.WComponentPeer.handleEvent(Ljava/awt/AWTEvent;)V+107
j  java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Ljava/awt/AWTEvent;)V+853
j  java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Ljava/awt/AWTEvent;)V+2
j  java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Ljava/awt/AWTEvent;)V+46
j  java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(I)Z+204
j  java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(ILjava/awt/Conditional;Ljava/awt/EventFilter;)V+30
j  java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(ILjava/awt/Conditional;Ljava/awt/Component;)V+11
j  java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(ILjava/awt/Conditional;)V+4
j  java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Ljava/awt/Conditional;)V+3
j  java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run()V+9
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
V  [jvm.dll+0xf33c9]
V  [jvm.dll+0x188a91]
V  [jvm.dll+0xf3587]
V  [jvm.dll+0xf35eb]
V  [jvm.dll+0x11e780]
V  [jvm.dll+0x1ea6c4]
V  [jvm.dll+0x18843c]
C  [msvcr71.dll+0x9565]
C  [kernel32.dll+0x51194]
C  [ntdll.dll+0x5b495]
C  [ntdll.dll+0x5b468]
```

I have never seen this before so I have no idea how to figure out what the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The .23 release has given us some of those too.  Report it as requested

> If you would like to submit a bug
>   report, please visit:
>      http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport/crash.jsp

and downgrade to an earlier version.  I believe at least .20 didn't have the problem.

Comment: How can i get an older version of java?

Answer (score 1):

Usually I google the message in this case "msvcrt.dll+0xa05b" but there were no matches.  You can log this bug.  The error occurred in a windows driver so I suggest you check your windows service pack level. However, if your problem persists you may need to try a newer or older version of Java.

Answer (score 0):

This is not going to be fun to debug. i suggest a google search like this one to maybe find an exsiting bug report dealing with this:

http://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1ASUT_enUS401US401&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=glTexSubImage2D1+core+dump#sclient=psy&hl=en&rlz=1C1ASUT_enUS401US401&source=hp&q=glTexSubImage2D+core+dump&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&pbx=1&fp=f478bdfafcb0c911